# Add additional data to model (downcasting?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, polymorphism

I got the following entity model which I use in Entity Framework:

```
public class User {
    public int    Id    { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to display to user on a view (MVVM in WPF, MVC in ASP.NET...), but along with other information that isn't available inside the database, but can be fetched at runtime from a service.

For this, I created a derived model class:

```
public class UserDetail : User {
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}
```

And now some gibberish code that describes what I want to achieve:

```
var users = _myContext.Users
               .ToList()
               .Select(x => new UserDetail() {
                         IsOnline = _myUserService.IsOnline(x.Id)
                     } = (UserDetail)x); // downcast x (User) to the new UserDetail instance
return View["MyView", users];
```

Now, downcasting doesn't work that way in C#.. do I have any other options to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constructor by copy to UserDetail.

```
public class UserDetail : User
{
    public UserDetail(User x)
    {
        this.Id = x.Id;
        this.Name = x.Name;
        this.EMail = x.EMail;
    }

    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}
```

(that kind of constructor can be generated by T4 if you have many class with this behaviour)

then, change your linq and use that constructor :

```
var users = _myContext.Users
           .ToList()
           .Select(x => new UserDetail(x) {
                     IsOnline = _myUserService.IsOnline(x.Id)
                 });
return View["MyView", users];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to copy the properties one by one, or write some code which will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate view model. You shouldn't expand your entity models to accommodate for properties required by your view. Then you can either copy properties one by one as zahorak suggested or use a library specificaly made for this task like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).